# Can a tooth be saved if it was accidentally knocked out from its socket?

Tags: dentistry, trauma, public-awareness

Due to trauma, e.g., from road accidents, sports, falls, etc a tooth may be removed entirely from its socket. Can this tooth be saved? If so, what should a person do at the accident site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sharing this knowledge with everyone of you.
Since it is very common for a healthy tooth to be knocked out and if a person is not aware of what steps should be taken and whether the tooth can be reimplanted or not then he/she will have to go for prosthesis, which has its expenses, and other complications. And no prosthesis is better than to have your own natural tooth in the socket.

So my answer is yes. A tooth may be saved and reimplanted in the socket after its avulsion (complete displacement from its socket)
However it's important to keep in mind that milk tooth/primary tooth/baby tooth **can not** be reimplanted. The reason being

> because of the potential for subsequent damage to developing permanent tooth germs

Reference-([www.aapd.org](http://www.aapd.org) › G_TraumaPDF Guideline on Management of Acute Dental Trauma - AAPD)

Now if the tooth is permanent then these steps should be followed at the accident site-

> •Find the tooth and pick it up by the crown (the white part). Avoid touching the root.
> •If the tooth is dirty, wash it briefly (max 10s) under cold running water and reposition it.Once the tooth is back in place, bite on a handkerchief to hold it in position.
> •If this is not possible, or for other reasons when replantation of the avulsed tooth is not possible (e.g., an unconscious patient), place the tooth in a glass of milk or another suitable storage medium and bring with the patient to the emergency clinic. The tooth can also be transported in the mouth, keeping it inside the lip or cheek if the patient is conscious. If the patient is very young, he/she could swallow the tooth – therefore it is advisable to get the patient to spit in a container and place the tooth in it. **Avoid storage in water!**
> •If there is access at the place of accident to special storage or transport media (e.g., tissue culture/transport medium, Hanks balanced storage medium (HBSS or saline) such media can preferably be used.
> •Seek emergency dental treatment immediately.

[Reference](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1600-9657.2012.01125.x)

The individual should visit the nearest dental clinic as soon as possible if he/she can not replant the tooth by himself/herself.

Now what all storage media can be used to transport the tooth to a dental clinic?

The excellent and most accessible storage media include cold milk> coconut water> egg white.
A table has been given in this [article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.scielo.br/pdf/bdj/v24n5/0103-6440-bdj-24-05-437.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwill6ryv6bqAhXx7HMBHVdfAu8QFjAGegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw1GlfBhQxlTTLVEWZp4gyek&cshid=1593415671173)
comparing different media for storage of a tooth.

I hope I have helped to share some knowledge.
Your doubts are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

If your tooth gets knocked out, the nerves, blood vessels and supporting tissues are damaged and can’t be repaired. So the avulsed teeth (displacement of a tooth from its socket) will need a root canal. However, the bone will reattach to the tooth's root once it’s restored into place. The chance of saving a tooth are highest in children; however, adult teeth may be saved. Only permanent teeth could be re-implanted. It is essential to get to the dentist as soon as possible when a tooth has been knocked out. It is quite necessary to avoid damaging the tooth further. Follow these suggestions to enhance the chances of saving your tooth:
Avoid touching the root surface itself.
Handle it carefully, rinse it with milk if the tooth is dirty.
Don’t wipe it to dry it off with any fabric. This could damage the tooth.
Keep the tooth moist. Drop it into a glass of milk. If you can’t do that, place the tooth in your mouth, between the cheek and gum.
Try slipping the tooth back to its socket. If it doesn’t go back into place smoothly and without pressure, then keep it moist. Then call for emergency dental and get to the dentist as soon as.
Suppose the tooth is not broken in pieces, it is always a good idea to try to save it.

If your [tooth is cracked](https://www.emergency-dental-365.com/procedures/broken-tooth/), make sure you don’t brush it, and at the earliest, make an appointment to see your dentist. Generally, the dentist will discuss with you the best course of action for repairing the crack, which could be one or a combination of fillings, crowns and root canal treatments.

[Reference](https://wmsmile.com/what-do-i-do-if-my-tooth-is-knocked-out/)

[Reference](https://www.backupcare.org/blog/how-to-save-a-tooth-that-gets-accidentally-knocked-out/)

Comment: Very nice and a well explained answer! Welcome to medical SE. But we work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be backed up with reliable references so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. If you have trouble with this, feel free to visit the help center or Medical Sciences Meta. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted

Comment: Reference - https://wmsmile.com/what-do-i-do-if-my-tooth-is-knocked-out/ and also https://www.backupcare.org/blog/how-to-save-a-tooth-that-gets-accidentally-knocked-out/.